# Update all records in a new table using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table with 20,000+ rows.  I keep a record of each client's daily stats from an ad campaign in the stats column.  It would be easier to call up the data for certain requests if I had the totals for Conversions and Spend calculated already in separate columns so I've added them.

Google_Records schema -

```
create_table "google_records", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "user_id"
 t.string   "date"
 t.text     "stats"
 t.text     "account_name"
 t.datetime "created_at",                                                        :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                                                        :null => false
 t.decimal  "total_cost",        :precision => 12, :scale => 2, :default => 0.0, :null => false
 t.integer  "total_conversions",                                :default => 0,   :null => false
end

add_index "google_records", ["date"], :name => "index_google_records_on_date"
```

Moving forward as records are created those columns will be populated.  However, I'm trying to figure out the best way to update the records that are already in the table.

Stats is a hash and I can get the total for one record like so:

```
user = User.find(6)
GoogleRecord.where(user_id: user).where(date: "20140328").map {|m| m.stats}.map{ |s| s.map{ |key,        value| value[:cost] || 0 } }.map {|m| m.inject(:+)}.compact.reduce(&:+)
=> 660.26
```

I'm currently thinking of writing a migration that could update all the tables at once.  Is this possible?

I'm having trouble getting the code to execute properly for even one user (although I do feel as though this may be an improper use of update_all)

```
("20140320".."20140323").each do |d|
  user = User.find(6)
  totalcost = GoogleRecord.where(user_id: user).where(date: d).map {|m| m.stats}.map{ |s| s.map{ |key, value| value[:cost] || 0 } }.map {|m| m.inject(:+)}.compact.reduce(&:+)
  GoogleRecord.where(user_id: user).where(date: d).update_all(:total_cost => totalcost)
end
```

Am I going in the right direction conceptually?

Update***

While trying to implement suggestions I realized not all users have these stats.  If I can get it working for just one user I'll be able to rewrite it for all users that have stats.  I believe I'm close to getting it to work for one user but I can't figure out where I'm messing up this each block.

Here is what I have:

```
user = User.find(6)
("20140320".."20140323").each do |d|
google_record = GoogleRecord.where(user_id: user).where(date: d)
total_cost = google_record.map {|m| m.stats.map{ |key, value| value[:cost] || 0 }}.compact.reduce(&:+) || 0
google_record.update_all(:total_cost => total_cost)
end
```

I'm now getting the following error that suggests this block is trying to insert the results of all records' `total_cost` into `:total_cost` but after rewriting this a few times I can't get it so that each separate `total_cost` calculation goes into the corresponding `:total_cost` column

```
←[1m←[36mGoogleRecord Load (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "google_records".* FROM "google_records"  WHERE "google_records"."user_id" = 6 AND "google_records"."date" = '20140320'←[0m
←[1m←[35mSQL (2.0ms)←[0m  UPDATE "google_records" SET "total_cost" =  258.92,35.82,18.58,47.78,1.42,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.44,82.07,2.19,5.87,0.0,0.0 WHERE   "google_records"."user_id" = 6 AND "google_records"."date" = '20140320'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "35.82": syntax error: UPDATE "google_records" SET "total_cost" = 258.92,35.82,18.58,47.78,1.42,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.44,82.07,2.19,5.87,0.0,0.0 WHERE "google_records"."user_id" = 6 AND "google_records"."date" = '20140320'
```

Comment: It's better to do a rake task for this as you may want to redo it at some point in the future (eg if you add more data-caching columns or if the totals get out of sync with the rest of the data).

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I agree.  That was my plan but I wanted to make sure it was functioning properly prior to setting that rake task and that is where I'm stuck - I can't get it to update the data set in the dev env with only 200 rows.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at the api doc. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

```
GoogleRecord.update_all(['total_cost = ?', totalcost], ['user_id = ? and date = ?', user.id, d])
```

Comment: Thanks @cenyongh - since I need to calculate the total for each as it runs (`totalcost`), would you suggest running `.each` on your line and within the each block calculate `totalcost` as I have in my question?

Comment: What i will suggest is change your schema, and store each stat record in db instead of store them as a hash string. After that you can use sql's sum and group by to do the work, which will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I thing that correct way is write it to the migration script. I edit your code and migration script can be look like this bellow:

```
# code in migration

class HandleGoogleRecordsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def up
        User.find_each do |user|
            ("20140320".."20140323").each do |d|
                google_record = GoogleRecord.where(user_id: user).where(date: d)
                totalcost = total_cost(google_record)
                google_record.update_all(:total_cost => totalcost)
            end
        end 
    end

    def down
        raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration.new "Dont allowed to migrate down."
    end

    def total_cost(google_record)
        # you can write it inside begin and rescue to return 0 if data in hash was incorrect
        result = 0
        begin
            result = google_record.map {|m| m.stats}.map{ |s| s.map{ |key, value| value[:cost] || 0 } }.map {|m| m.inject(:+)}.compact.reduce(&:+)
        rescue => e
            Rails.logger.error("google_record #{google_record.inspect} doesnt count total cost")
            result = 0  
        end
        result
    end

end
```